# Autorotation only working in simulator not on device (IOS 7.1)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rotation

I've tried various approaches posted on here to setup correctly AutoRotation in IOS7 using storyboards. What I have "should" work as it works perfectly well in the simulator but when I load the code onto a device (iPad or iPhone) it doesn't rotate.

***[UPDATE:  Code now DOES rotate on iPad but not Mini or iPhone???]***

**In the simulator (and IPAD):**

- Navigate to controller:  Loads the correct orientation
- Rotate the Controller:   Only allows specified orientations

**On the IPHONE/IPAD Mini:**

- Navigate to Controller: Does NOT change orientation
- Rotate the Controller:  Only allows specified orientations

I have NO idea what the difference is.  If anybody has any suggestions it would be SUPER helpful because its kind of driving me crazy here.

The approach I followed is detailed below:

I followed the approach that was mentioned somewhere and I created a subclass of `UINavigationController` called `RotationControlledViewController` (code is below).

Then I made `LandscapeViewController` and `PortraitViewController` which subclass `UIViewController`.  The View Controllers i want to be locked to a specific orientation inherit from these classes instead of `UIViewController`

(and yes - i did make sure my rotation lock was disabled on the device)

**RotationViewController**

```
//
//  RotationControlledViewController.m
//  ASGAARD
//
//  Created by Jeff Stein on 2/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jeff Stein. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RotationControlledViewController.h"

@interface RotationControlledViewController ()

@end

@implementation RotationControlledViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    BOOL ret =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
//    NSLog(@"--Auto Roatate Reported %d", ret);
    return ret;
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger ret = [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];

//    NSLog(@"--supportedInterfaceOrientations: %d", ret);


    return ret;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation ret =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];

//    NSLog(@"--preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: %ld",ret);
    return ret;
}


@end
```

**LandscapeViewController**

```
//
//  LandscapeViewController.m
//  ASGAARD
//
//  Created by Jeff Stein on 2/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jeff Stein. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LandscapeViewController.h"
#import "objc/message.h"

@interface LandscapeViewController ()

@end

@implementation LandscapeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
    objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

    NSLog(@"Issuing a rotation message (hopefully");
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

@end
```

**PortraitViewController**

```
//
//  PortraitViewController.m
//  ASGAARD
//
//  Created by Jeff Stein on 2/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jeff Stein. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PortraitViewController.h"
#import "objc/message.h"

@interface PortraitViewController ()

@end

@implementation PortraitViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];

    objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}



@end
```

**UPDATE -- Additional Anomalies:**

On IPAD Mini where things aren't exactly working correctly I am in landscape and navigate to a view that "should" be portrait.  It launches an alert that is aligned portrait but the view itself comes up landscape.  See the comparison:

I notice that the screen shots come out in portrait (as does the alert).  Which implies to me the mini "thinks" its in portrait mode but somehow its not updating the view controller correctly.
[image: IPAD Mini - alert gets correct rotation??]

The IPAD obviously looks correct.
[image: IPAD - everything is correct]

I made a sample project on GitHUB that demonstrates the issue:

https://github.com/jlss/RotationIssues

Comment: What simulator are you running the code on, and what iOS version does the device have?

Comment: Whats your settings in the `Info.plist`? Have you got different settings for iPad/iPhone?

Comment: Using `objc_msgSend` seems dirty, especially if its undocumented, thats probably your main problem! Though as for why it works on the Mini and not the normal iPad that is weird!

Comment: Anybody have a suggestion as to a better way to force the controller to rotate?  I've tried the other options such as setStatusBar and they don't seem to work well.

Comment: The code you've got (and your subclass) should be doing it all for you. You probably want to update the new interface orientation when you push/pop a view controller. Override `setViewControllers:animated:` in your sub class (I think this is called for both push/pops) and call `super` and then try calling [`[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIViewController/attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation)

Comment: Or put that call ([`[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIViewController/attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation)) in your base `LandscapeViewController` and `PortraitViewController` classes in maybe `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @Rich - thanks but didn't seem to work.  So frustrating.

Comment: @Jeef did you ever figure out the solution to this? any additional info would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately no - i ended up locking the rotation to landscape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you seem to be running into here is related to IOS7 onwards.  From what I've seen the only way to do what you seek is to actually add a second navigation controller into your stack with a modal segue.  Alternatively you could try to turn off AutoLayout.  Neither of these options I think are what you want to hear.